# Как сделать свой сайт корневым в Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

если перейти по ссылке localhost:8080/ то открывается вебприложение, которое находится в папке ROOT. Как настроить томкат, что бы корневым был сайт test(что бы мое приложение, которое лежит в папке test открывалось, когда пишешь в браузере localhost:8080. Не перенося содержимое папки test в папку ROOT)? Что бы на него можно было попасть через localhost:8080, а не localhost:8080/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты:

- Самый простой способ - заместить **ROOT** вашим приложением. Рекомендую его использовать.
- Сложный способ:

  1. Останавливаете сервер
  2. В файле **server.xml** меняете параметр `autoDeploy` на `false`
  3. Потом читаете вот это текст [The context container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)
  4. В файле **server.xml** прописываете `context` для своего приложения
  5. Запускаете сервер
- Обычный способ - поставить перед Tomcat reverse proxy и менять путь в нем

Comment: Я знаю что так можно. Но можно ли настроить томкат что б корневым приложением было мое, которое лежит в папке test, а не в папке ROOT

Comment: тогда дополните вопрос, так как сейчас в нем нет этой информации

Comment: Там вообще то написано как настроить что бы корневым был такой то такой то сайт

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Можите подсказать?

Comment: обновил ответ. скажите какой вариант выбрали?

Comment: сложный. Спасибо что подсказали